# Php form upload and email

Tags: php, html, forms

I have the following code, ideally, it is expected that the user shall upload a file(image/video) when submitting the form, but it is not compulsory though.

```
<?php

$to = "someone@example.com";
$fromEmail = $_POST['fieldFormEmail']; 
$fromName = $_POST['fieldFormName']; 
$subject = $_POST['fieldSubject']; 
$message = $_POST['fieldDescription'];

/* GET File Variables */ 
$tmpName = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name']; 
$fileType = $_FILES['attachment']['type']; 
$fileName = $_FILES['attachment']['name']; 

/* Start of headers */ 
$headers = "From: $fromName"; 

if (file($tmpName)) { 
  /* Reading file ('rb' = read binary)  */
  $file = fopen($tmpName,'rb'); 
  $data = fread($file,filesize($tmpName)); 
  fclose($file); 

  /* a boundary string */
  $randomVal = md5(time()); 
  $mimeBoundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$randomVal}x"; 

  /* Header for File Attachment */
  $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" ;
  $headers .= " boundary=\"{$mimeBoundary}\""; 

  /* Multipart Boundary above message */
  $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . 
  "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" . 
  "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . 
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . 
  $message . "\n\n"; 

  /* Encoding file data */
  $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data)); 

  /* Adding attchment-file to message*/
  $message .= "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" . 
  "Content-Type: {$fileType};\n" . 
  " name=\"{$fileName}\"\n" . 
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . 
  $data . "\n\n" . 
  "--{$mimeBoundary}--\n"; 
} 

$flgchk = mail ("$to", "$subject", "$message", "$headers"); 

if($flgchk){
  echo "A email has been sent to: $to";
 }
else{
  echo "Error in Email sending";
}
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Email Attachment Without Upload - Excellent Web World</title>
<style>
body{ font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px;}
th{ background:#999999; text-align:right; vertical-align:top;}
input{ width:181px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="Contact.php" method="post" name="mainform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
       <tr>
        <th>Your Name</th>
        <td><input name="fieldFormName" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Your Email</th>
        <td><input name="fieldFormEmail" type="text"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <td><input name="fieldSubject" type="text" id="fieldSubject"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Comments</th>
        <td><textarea name="fieldDescription" cols="20" rows="4" id="fieldDescription"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Attach Your File</th>
      <td><input name="attachment" type="file"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
<html>
```

The problem that i am facing is,

1. it runs on page load, and
2. if file has not been uploaded, it throws a warning.

I tried putting the file upload part under "if filename exists" condition, but then the email does not send the attachment
Please help.
This file name is Contact.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it runs on page load

enclose mail send feature in

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit']) && ($_POST['Submit']) == 'Send' )
{
  /* process only when submit button whose name='Submit' 
     and value= 'Send' is pressed
     entire PHP code */
}
```

> if file has not been uploaded, it throws a warning.

check before attaching it in PHP

```
if((empty($_POST['attachment'])) || (empty($_FILES['attachment']))){
    //file is not attached, show error
}else{
 //file is attached, process it and send via mail
}
```