# Unchecked checkbox for action in php

Tags: php, html

i wanted to know how to detect for and unchecked check box and make it perform and action.Basically if the checkbox is unchecked it should load another page. This doesnt seem to be working , any help?

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['checkbox1'])) 
{
    $swag=fopen("empty.php","r");
}
?>
```

The HTML bit:

```
<html>
<title>Zeromilez | Shop</title>
<!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.--><script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script><script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/source-sans-pro:n2,n4:default;atomic-age:n4:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="header-wrapper">
    <div id="header" class="container">
        <div id="logo">
            <h1><a href='#'>Zeromilez.com</a></h1>
        </div>
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li ><a href="index.php" accesskey="1" title=""><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw fa-2x"></i> Home</a></li>

                <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#" title="" class="active" accesskey="4"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-2x"></i>     shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="feedback.php" accesskey="5" title=""><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x"></i> Feedback</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="banner" class="container"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST">
    <div id="three-column" class="container">
      <div id="tbox1">
        <div class="title">
          <p>
            <input name="name" type="text" id="textfield" style="background-color:#4D4D4D;margin:0;color:#FFF; text-align:center;" value="Fox's berries-500gms" disabled>
          </p>
          <h2><img src="fox.jpg" height="90" width="100"></h2>
        </div>
        <p>
          <input name="cost" type="text" id="textfield2" value="Rs 100" style="background-color:#4D4D4D;color:#fff; text-align:center; padding:0; margin:0;" disabled>
        </p>
        <p>
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1">
          Add to cart
          <label for="checkbox1"></label>
        </p>
      </div>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
      </p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1">
  </form>
</div>
<div id="copyright" class="container">
  <p>&#169; Zeromilez.com 2014 | All rights reserved | Made with &#10084; in Bangalore, India  
  </p><p>Follow us:<br/><img src="facebook.png" width="30" height="30" alt=""/><img src="twitter.png" width="30" height="30" alt=""/><img src="google.png" width="30" height="30" alt=""/><img src="yahoo.png" width="30" height="30" alt=""/><img src="pinterest.png" width="30" height="30" alt=""/></p><div id ="about_me" >
  <p>About Me:<br/><img src="about_me.png" width="100" height="100" alt=""><br/>Hi, I am Mohit Bhasi, a 16 year old aspiring web developer. Hope you all enjoy my first website :)</p></div>
</h4></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your html.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When receiving the POST parameters in the php side, if the parameter relative to the checkbox comes in, that's because the checkbox is selected. If the parameter doesn't come in the POST parameters it's unchecked.

You can do something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['checkbox_parameter']){
    echo "Checkbox is selected!";
}
else {
    echo "Checkbox not selected.";
}
```

Comment: so can i use an else in php, i am a newbie

Comment: @user3895531 Yes you can.

Comment: how can i check if submit button is clicked along with the else statement

Comment: @user3895531 : for your last comment, check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25113639/php-form-upload-and-email/25113823#25113823

Comment: U should use require/include and not fopen to get `empty.php`