# PHP Form Error - HTML & Image upload

Tags: php, html, forms, email

So a bit of quick background. I've only just started getting into php and i've been on this for a few days now. Apologies if my code is messy but I've tried to tag as much as i can.

I have a form where on completion, 3 things are supposed to happen.

1. Email is sent to the recipient with all the details that were filled out are sent through formatted nicely in a html table + image attachment.
2. Plain text email is sent to the form applicant with a thank you.
3. Also, on success of form submission the form applicant is then
   automatically directed to a "thank you" page.

• All is fine if all required fields filled in AND image is uploaded/attached. The whole process is run without error.

• If an image is NOT uploaded/attached, I get the following message

> Warning: file(): Filename cannot be empty in /home/website/public_html/repairs/contact.php on line  49
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/website/public_html/repairs/contact.php:49) in /home/website/public_html/repairs/contact.php on line 108

followed by an email received that is seen with all the html tags/code/plain text.

The plain text email sent to the "form applicant" with a thank you is still received.

See my php code below

```php
<?php
 
 // multiple recipients
$to = $_REQUEST['sendto'] ; 
$from = $_REQUEST['email'] ;

// subject
$subject = "Repairs Request Form"; 
$fname = $_REQUEST['fname'] ; 

$message = '
<html>
<body>
<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666; border="1px" "cellpadding="10">
<tr><td style="background: #eee;" colspan="2"><strong>Repairs Request Enquiry</strong></td></tr>
<tr><td><strong>First Name:</strong> </td><td>' . strip_tags($_POST['fname']) . '</td></tr>
<tr><td><strong>Last Name:</strong> </td><td>' . strip_tags($_POST['lname']) . '</td></tr>
<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>' . strip_tags($_POST['email']) . '</td></tr>
<tr><td><strong>Contact Number:</strong> </td><td>' . strip_tags($_POST['phone']) . '</td></tr>
<tr><td><strong>Address:</strong> </td><td>' . strip_tags($_POST['address']) . '</td></tr>
<tr><td><strong>Suburb:</strong> </td><td>' . strip_tags($_POST['suburb']) . '</td></tr>
<tr><td><strong>Postcode:</strong> </td><td>' . strip_tags($_POST['postcode']) . '</td></tr>
<tr><td><strong>Type of repair:</strong> </td><td>' . strip_tags($_POST['repair']) . '</td></tr>
<tr><td><strong>Nature of the problem:</strong> </td><td>' . $_POST['problem'] . '</td></tr>
<tr><td><strong>Is this urgent:</strong> </td><td>' . $_POST['urgent'] . '</td></tr>
<tr><td><strong>Type of Urgency:</strong> </td><td>' . $_POST['urgent_type'] . '</td></tr>
<tr><td><strong>Master key access required:</strong> </td><td>' . $_POST['masteraccess'] . '</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>'
;

 //ATTACHMENT START

/* GET File Variables */ 
$tmpName = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name']; 
$fileType = $_FILES['attachment']['type']; 
$fileName = $_FILES['attachment']['name']; 

/* Start of headers */ 
$headers = "From: $from"; 

//**XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  PROBLEM IS HERE XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX**    

if (file($tmpName)) { 
  /* Reading file ('rb' = read binary)  */
  $file = fopen($tmpName,'rb'); 
  $data = fread($file,filesize($tmpName)); 
  fclose($file); 

 
  /* a boundary string */
  $randomVal = md5(time()); 
  $mimeBoundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$randomVal}x"; 
 
  /* Header for File Attachment */
  $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" ;
  $headers .= " boundary=\"{$mimeBoundary}\""; 
 
  /* Multipart Boundary above message */
  $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . 
  "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" . 
  "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . 
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . 
  $message . "\n\n"; 
 
  /* Encoding file data */
  $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data)); 
 
  /* Adding attchment-file to message*/
  $message .= "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" . 
  "Content-Type: {$fileType};\n" . 
  " name=\"{$fileName}\"\n" . 
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . 
  $data . "\n\n" . 
  "--{$mimeBoundary}--\n"; 
} 
 //END OF ATTACHMENT

 
  //Message/email to the customer.
 $headers2 = "From: noreply@website.com.au"; 
 $subject2 = "Thank you. Your e-mail has been logged."; 
 $autoreply = "Thank you. Your e-mail has been logged.
We will attend to your request and be in touch shortly.
Rest assured, we are doing all we can to speed up this process.
Regards,
Repairs Team";

 
 if($from == '') {print "You have not entered an email, please go back and try again";} 
 else { 
 if($fname == '') {print "You have not entered your first name";} 
 else { 
 $send = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
 $send2 = mail($from, $subject2, $autoreply, $headers2); 
 if($send) 
 {header( "Location: http://www.website.com.au/thankyoupage/thankyou.html" );} 
 else 
 {print "We encountered an error sending your mail, please notify webmaster@website.com.au"; } 
 }
}
?>
```

I tried to follow this post but I'm just loosing it.
[Php form upload and email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25113639/php-form-upload-and-email?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can anyone answer.. As a work around, since no errors occur when uploading an image to the form. Would it be possible if i had an "if" no image is uploaded use an image stored on a server? I can create a dummy image and have it emailed each time.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send headers to redirect a page if they have already been set.

You can try to flush the object by using `ob_flush()` at the start of your page.

Comment: David, how did you get on with this?

Comment: Hi Lee,
Im very new to PHP so not familiar with `ob_flush()` but am going to try this in the coming days. To temporarily fix the problem Ive placed `if` no image is attached, attach "this" image sitting on the server... I will try your suggestion in the coming days and let you know. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

change

```
if (file($tmpName)) {
```

to

```
if($_FILES["attachment"]["error"] != 0) {
```

Comment: Please explain *why* this is what OP needs to do; providing code changes without context or explanation helps no one.

Comment: Hey Ram, the email submitted is now html formatted correctly when received. But the applicant still gets the same errors on form submit + the following as well...  
Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in website/contact.php on line 56/57

Comment: Your code looks ok, It look like that you have permission issue. try to check the value of `allow_url_fopen`. if it's false than you have to talk with your web host provider to enable it. You can check it like `var_dump(ini_get('allow_url_fopen'));`